# How can I implement a drawer navigation with bottom tabs, but without having two nested navigators?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am trying to implement an interface (in a react-native - expo app), where there is one main navigator - drawer. But only for UI reasons I want also a bottom bar with tabs, that looks like bottom tabs navigator from react-navigation.

What is important - I don't want nested navigators as there will be only one main route at a time - I want this to be managed by single navigator (drawer navigator).

The bottom tabs should only switch between screens of drawer navigator. All of the screens are available all the time, regardless of the current route. If I would nest tabs nav inside drawer nav - then I would have to multiplicate al the screens, because tabs will only lead to the same screens that are already in the drawer.

How can I achieve this? Maybe some similar component (in UI) but not from react-navigation (only for switching between drawer screens)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, after a long research I found out that react-navigation package doesn't offer such functionality without the need to nest navigators (and bear it's consequences).
For anyone else dealing with that - I just implemented my own bottom buttons bar and put that component so it is visible all the time.

Three important things:

1. It has to be put inside NavigationContainer but outside the (drawer) navigator so it is visible all the time. So put it as a sibling to real navigator.
2. To be able to get navigation object (and be able to switch between screens) outside the navigator you can just use "useNavigation" hook in the bottom tabs component.
3. To be able to open drawer from bottom tabs you have to use special object - DrawerActions.

   import { useNavigation, ParamListBase, DrawerActions } from "@react-navigation/native";

   //inside component:
   const navigation = useNavigation();
   //...
   navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());